# Decrypt secret key using crypto js which is encrypted from Java

Tags: javascript, java

I have below encryption written in Java using javax.crypto. Now I want to decrypt the encrypted string from client side and use it. I tried to follow some posts on the internet, but not getting proper results.  Can you please help me to figure out on how to decrypt this in client side in JavaScript using crypto-js?

```
import org.apache.commons.codec.binary.Base64;

import javax.crypto.BadPaddingException;
import javax.crypto.Cipher;
import javax.crypto.IllegalBlockSizeException;
import javax.crypto.NoSuchPaddingException;
import javax.crypto.spec.IvParameterSpec;
import javax.crypto.spec.SecretKeySpec;
import java.nio.charset.StandardCharsets;
import java.security.InvalidAlgorithmParameterException;
import java.security.InvalidKeyException;
import java.security.NoSuchAlgorithmException;

public class EncryptDecryptImpl {

    private static final String secretKey = "my-secret-key";

    private static String encrypt(String mix, String initVector) {
        try {
            IvParameterSpec ivParameterSpec = new IvParameterSpec(initVector.getBytes(StandardCharsets.UTF_8));
            SecretKeySpec secretKeySpec = new SecretKeySpec(mix.getBytes(StandardCharsets.UTF_8),"AES");
            Cipher cipher = Cipher.getInstance("AES/CBC/PKCS5PADDING");
            cipher.init(Cipher.ENCRYPT_MODE, secretKeySpec, ivParameterSpec);
            byte[] encrypted = cipher.doFinal(secretKey.getBytes());
            return new String(Base64.encodeBase64(encrypted));
        } catch (NoSuchPaddingException | NoSuchAlgorithmException | InvalidAlgorithmParameterException |
                InvalidKeyException | BadPaddingException | IllegalBlockSizeException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return null;
    }

    public static String aesEncryptedSecretKey() {
        String encryptedSecretKey;
        String key = "Bar12345Bar12345"; // 128 bit key
        String initVector = "RandomInitVector"; // 16 bytes IV
        encryptedSecretKey = EncryptDecryptImpl.encrypt(key, initVector);
        return encryptedSecretKey;
    }
}
```

Something like this in JavaScript using crypto-js:

```
const encryptedBase64Key = 'bXVzdEJlMTZCeXRlc0tleQ==';
const parsedBase64Key = enc.Base64.parse(encryptedBase64Key);

const encryptedCipherText = 'dItqis/6MoMJ4mKWDt2zVw==';
const decodeBase64Key = enc.Base64.parse(encryptedCipherText);

const decryptedData = AES.decrypt({
    cipherText: decodeBase64Key
    }, parsedBase64Key, {
        mode: mode.CBC,
        padding: pad.Pkcs7
})
```

Comment: In the JavaScript code the IV is not taken into account. This must first be parsed with the Utf8 encoder and then passed to the `decrypt()` method, [here](https://cryptojs.gitbook.io/docs/#custom-key-and-iv). Also, the parameter in the `CipherParams` object is `ciphertext` and not `cipherText`, [here](https://cryptojs.gitbook.io/docs/#the-cipher-output). If you then use consistent data in the Java and CryptoJS code, it works.